# Correct string to pass to route() when getting Route that is inside a Route Group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Route Group, pasted below, inside of which there is a Route named `clients`. I want to use the `route()` function in a `view` to get that `clients` `route`. What is the correct string to pass to the function.

The below includes one of the things I tried, in terms of setting up the group, which was to add `'name'=>'company.'` to the Group method arguments. I've tried it with and without a `.` after the group name. I'm not sure if I'm going wrong in the way I'm defining the Group, or the way I'm calling `route()`, or both.

```
Route::group(['name' => 'company.', 'middleware' => ['auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');

});
```

If the `clients` `Route` wasn't inside a `Group`, I would get it in my view like this:

```
route('clients');
```

I have tried `route('company.clients');` with no luck.

Laravel 5.6

Thanks

Comment: change `name` to `as` on the group, and then use `route('company.clients')`

Comment: Route::get('clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');

try without the / on clients

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy that's done it. Feel free to make it an official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(['as' => 'company.', 'middleware' => ['auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');

});
```

And now you can use  `route('company.clients');`